# Adding and Removing SherlockActionBarItems

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

My activity allows a user to either make changes to his selected preferences or skip to the next screen. By default the action item will be skip, however as soon as the preferences have been changes, that button changes to save. How can i add and remove the actionitems from the SherlockActionBar ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it out myself, but since ActionBar Buttons are essentially Menu items, you can do so by using the Activity's `Menu` variable created during `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

Like so:

```
public class Sample extends SherlockActivity {
Menu activityMenu;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);
        activityMenu = menu;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you can normally call the methods you need through `activityMenu`.

See the entire list here: [Menu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html)

And for more insightful reading: [Menus - Changing menu items at runtime](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu)